# I have a problem linking task with Invoice in zoho php API

Tags: php, api, zoho, zohobooks

I have written a code in php zoho api which create task and assign it to the invoice.

> Create task is working fine and its creating task into zoho panel but
>   its not linking with the invoice.

Please find below code:

```
$crmid = "3051265000001316001"; // customer id
$realted_to_id = "3051265000003854220"; // invoice id
$task_data = array(
    'Subject' => "New Invoice - 22", 
    'Due Date' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("10-10-2020")),
    'Status' => "In Progress",
    'Priority' => "High",
    'CONTACTID' => $crmid,
    'RELATEDTOID' => $realted_to_id,
    'Related To' => "HO000001",
    'SEMODULE' => "CustomModule5001",
);

/* Insert Task in zoho */
$task = $zoho_api->insert_record('Tasks', $task_data);
```

> To link Task with Invoice, I'm using two fields `RELATEDTOID` and
>   `Related To` but its not linking :(

There is no error message coming.

Could anyone help on this please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some logs or error messages ?

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin There is no error message. Task is working fine but only issue is to assign to invoice.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who are seeking to get answer of this.

```
In v1 api, please provide the invoice records details in xmlData as "<FL 
val="SEMODULE">Invoices</FL> <FL val="SEID">{Invoice_record_id}</FL>".

In v2 api, Please provide the invoice details in JSON body as ("$se_module": 
"Invoices", "What_Id": "{Invoice_record_id}").
```

@ZOHO developer community seems poor to answer this question.